# Better way to fill variables from array (Destructuring assignment)

Tags: javascript, python, strsplit

I have this Code in my Javascript File:

```
const blfTypeAndId = DDid.split("PrerequisitesSelect");
const blfType = blfTypeAndId[0];
const blfId = blfTypeAndId[1];
```

The blfType is after this either 'block', 'line' or 'field' and the blfId is _B1_L1_F1 while the numbers can be different (this is just for field, for line it would be _B1_L1 and block just _B1)

In a world where Python and Javascript are combined I would just do this:

```
const blfType, const blfId = DDid.split("PrerequisitesSelect");
```

Is there a nice way in Javascript to still do this in one line or is my first written code already the best possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good job for the [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
const blfTypeAndId = DDid.split("PrerequisitesSelect");
const [blfType, blfId] = blfTypeAndId;
```

or even just

```
const [blfType, blfId] = DDid.split("PrerequisitesSelect");
```

Comment: oh nice, thats exactly what i wanted, thank you :)